# Removing patch on matlab figure without close function

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I draw a square on matlab figure as below.

```
x = [-1 1 1 -1];
y = [-1 -1 1 1];
h=figure(1)
patch(x,y,'red')
axis([-2 2 -2 2])
```

Result is as below.

[image]

I would like to erase the red square without using matlab close function, as below.

[image]

How can I erase the square without closing figure?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Specify an [output to `patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#zmw57dd0e538476) and [`delete`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying an output to [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) not only allows you to [access](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [modify](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) the object's properties, it also allows you to pass it to other functions. In this case, you can pass the object to the [`delete`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) function, which will clear it from memory.

For example:

```
x = [-1 1 1 -1];
y = [-1 -1 1 1];
h = figure(1);
p = patch(x, y, 'red');
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
pause(0.5); % Wait half a second
delete(p)
```

Note that while `delete` clears the referenced object from memory, it does not clear the variable from the workspace. You can use [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) for housekeeping, if necessary.